# How can I find what are possible errors of Firebase SDK methods?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

It is so often that I use a method, for example

```
open func commitChanges(completion: FirebaseAuth.UserProfileChangeCallback? = nil)
```

which says it will either return no error, which is good or some error they call `UserProfileChangeCallback`

I searched for it and only thing I got that it is an alias to optional error

```
public typealias UserProfileChangeCallback = (Error?) -> Swift.Void
```

but I can't find what are the possible errors that can be returned so I can program a specific handler for it!
And it's not only this; I can't find any details for any errors returned in Firebase docs.
Do you know where can I find them or how can I dig them out from the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for Swift is open source. That would be a good place to look for those error codes. For example, I found [this class](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Auth/Source/FIRAuthErrorUtils.m) detailing the Auth errors. Is that what you're looking for?